# git branching. Shouldn't the file system be updating when I branch?

Tags: git

I've been reading the tutorial [here.](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) Which explains the basics of creating branches with git.

I'm following the instructions as close as I can tell. However, the behavior I'm getting is different from what the site suggests. Namely this point:

> Git resets your working directory to look like the snapshot of the commit that the branch you check out points to.

The problem I'm having is that filesystem changes don't seem to stay on their own branch.

I set up a test project like this:

```
MyProject 
  | .git
  | file1.txt 
  | file2.txt
```

From there, I run

```
git checkout -b my_new_feature
```

And then I create a new file in the directory.

```
MyProject 
  | .git
  | file1.txt 
  | file2.txt
  | myfeature.txt
```

Now, how I *thought* it worked was that the new file `myfeature.txt` was "on" the branch `my_feature`, and thus isn't "seen" at all by `master`.

So, I switched back to master expecting to have the new text file disappear

```
git checkout master
```

but it's still there. It's like I didn't branch at all.

```
MyProject 
  | .git
  | file1.txt 
  | file2.txt
  | myfeature.txt
```

Just to see what happened, I tried merging the two

```
git merge my_feature
```

And it says that it's already up to date.

Am I confused as to what exactly a `branch` is, or did I do something wrong..?

Comment: The new file is untracked, so git isn't going to remove it when you switch branches.  Read this page from the tutorial for how it works: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you checkout `my_feature`, and create the new file, try running `git status`. You'll see Git say something like this:

```
Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    foo.txt
```

At this point in time, Git doesn't know about the new file. It has no idea what it is. Git isn't tracking it, so it's an *untracked* file. Because it doesn't know about it, it will simply ignore it, so swapping back to `master` leaves `foo.txt` (the new file) there.

If you are on your `my_feature` branch and then add and commit the file:

```
git add foo.txt
git commit -m "Added my new file"
```

Then try running `git status`. You'll see:

```
On branch my_feature
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Now Git knows about the new file, as you've added and committed it. It now knows the state of this file, and that it exists only on `my_feature`, as that's where you first added it to your repository. Now you can `git checkout master`, and you'll see `foo.txt` disappear, because Git knows that that file doesn't exist on master.

TL;DR: until you tell Git about a file, it doesn't know what to do with it, so will just ignore it.

At any point if you're confused with what git is doing, often `git status` will help clear things up.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you actually *add* (using `git add`) and *commit* (using `git commit`) the new files, nothing belongs to anything. It’s just a directory with—to Git—unrelated files.

If you are on your `my_new_feature` branch, and add and commit the file `myfeature.txt`, and *then* switch back to `master` (which does not know about that file), then you will see it disappear from your working directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to track the new file for git to know it is in the new branch. Try adding it and committing it.